# "argument 'pattern' is missing" - showing up after every command after calling readRDS()

Tags: r

I encountered this weird issue in R, when after I call `readRDS(<file_path>)` it reads the file in correctly, but throws an `argument "pattern" is missing, with no default` error. I would not mind if it was just one time, but it throws this error every time I call any other function after `readRDS()`, for example:

```
> fit <- readRDS(<file_path>)
argument "pattern" is missing, with no default

> head(fit)
<SHOWS THE CORRECT OUTPUT!> 
argument "pattern" is missing, with no default

> head(<another_file_read_by_fread()>)
<SHOWS THE CORRECT OUTPUT!> 
argument "pattern" is missing, with no default
```

It is frustrating and makes no sense to me, does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Did you try restarting R/RStudio ?

Comment: I did, and nothing changes. Now you gave me an idea and I checked whether it works on my local RStudio (the above issue only happens on a cluster), and it seems to work without an error, despite using the same R version.